# Yii: init module when it's not in config

Tags: php, yii

I have some modules in my Yii project, and I would like to init them only if current user is privileged to use this module.

Here's what I did: In SiteController I fetch the db table with user-module relations and got an array of modules'  names. Then I've wanted to load each available module when no moudules are defined in config. I couldn't find any operator or method to do this. Is there a way to realize this without making workaround?

Another thing I think about is to cancel module init in beforeControllerAction of each module, but I stil can't figure this out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really better to use `beforeControllerAction` for checking access rights as follows:

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
{
   if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
   {
      // this method is called before any module controller action is performed
      // you may place customized code here              
      if(!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('getMyModule')){
          throw new CHttpException(403, Yii::t('yii','You do not have sufficient permissions to access.'));
      }             
      return true;
   }
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank! This's nice solution if I have small amount of modules. But if I have 100+ modules (it's not for now :-) ) I'd prefer to load only allowed 5-15 of them. The question is can I define the requiered modules only or I have do it with all of them?

Comment: @Switcher modules are not loaded all at once. Yii use lazy load and module files will be loaded only after request.

Comment: Oh, ok. I've never tried to use them before. Thanks for you help!